# Sorting not working in DataFormWebPart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sorting, data-form-web-part

We have just migrated our site from SP2010 to SP2013 where we have used DataFormWebPart in many pages. But after migration the sorting is not working properly on those pages.

Sorting only works when we click on column title.
If we click on small arrow icon near header title and select either 'Ascending' or 'Descending', its not working from context menu.

It used to work earlier in SP 2010
Here is screenshot of the same.

[image]

**Update**

Same is observed when I create new DataFormWebPart in SharePoint 2013. Does anyone encountered this problem earlier ? IS this a bug in SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: Facing the same problem here. Please let us know in case you find any work around.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't got any perfect solution, I am posting down a fix which I made with the help of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("th.ms-vh > table").click(function(){
        var intervalID = setInterval(startCheck, 500); // >>> on table header(column) click, execute startCheck function continously(every 0.5 second)
        setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(intervalID);}, 5000); // >> stop execution after 5 seconds
    });
});

function startCheck(){
    if( $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Descending'][type='option']").length > 0 ){ // >>> Check if context menu is loaded            

        // >>> get onclick script from <li>
        var desScript = $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Descending'][type='option']").attr("onmenuclick").toString().replace("descending","'descending'"); 
        var ascScript = $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Ascending'][type='option']").attr("onmenuclick").toString().replace("ascending","'ascending'");

        // >>> set onclick and href attribute of <a> tags for Ascending and Descending menu options
        $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Descending'] > a").attr("href", desScript);
        $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Ascending'] > a").attr("href", ascScript);

        $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Descending'] > a")[0].setAttribute('onclick',desScript);
        $("li.ms-core-menu-item[text='Ascending'] > a")[0].setAttribute("onclick", ascScript);

    }
}
```